# ':app:kaptDebugKotlin' error on android studio 3 stable version with room 1(RC)

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-room, kapt

I still get this error while compiling my project written in kotlin :

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:kaptDebugKotlin'.
>   Internal compiler error. See log for more details

Does anyone have a workaround or solution for this bug? I've seen almost all answers around this problem but non was useful at this level.

I should add that the project was working fine without changing anything from gradle all of a sudden I got that compile error

Comment: What does the Gradle console say? Normally a rebuild fixes this kind of issues (unless there's an issue on your code, which in that case the stacktrace printed on the console will evidence).

Comment: You should inspect the gradle console, probably there is an issue with your Room code or sometimes there is some diffrerent error - unfortunately you must seek for it in gradle console, the error you get is just too general, maybe soon there will be more clear error appearing

Comment: Can you try to build the project from the terminal? E.g., `./gradlew clean assembleDebug`. Gradle should print you all diagnostic messages.